# Assigning apollo mutations with a ternary in an onClick?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, apollo-client, tsx

I am new to typescript and migrating a react frontend to learn. I am currently having trouble with my login/registration component - a ternary operator is assigned to an onClick handler which dictates whether the login or signup mutation are executed. I implemented a workaround where I wrapped the mutations in functions, but it looks dirty.

Here is a barebones example, which returns a type assignment error because the values in the ternary do not share attributes with the onClick handler. I can provide a more robust, reproduceable example if necessary.

```
const Auth = () => {
const history = useHistory();
const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    login: true,
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    username: '',
    password: '',
    email: ''
});

const [loginMutation] = useMutation(LOGIN_MUTATION, {
    onCompleted: (response) => {
        //...
    }
});
const [signupMutation] = useMutation(SIGNUP_MUTATION, {
    variables: {
        //...
    },
    onCompleted: (response) => {
        // ...
    }
});

return (
    <>
        {!formState.login && (
            display extra inputs for registration form
        )}
        username and password fields

        <button onClick={formState.login ? login : signup}>
            {formstate.login ? login: signup}
        </button>
    </>
)
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly guessed `onClick` has signature `(e:MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void` while mutation has a different signature (something along the lines of `(options?: MutationFunctionOptions<T>) => Promise<Result>`). So, when you say, `onClick={login}` you are essentially doing this: `onClick={e => login(e)}` which is wrong.

One way to fix it is to write an inline function

```tsx
<button onClick={() => formState.login ? login() : signup()}>
 {formstate.login ? login: signup}
</button>
```

Comment: Ah thanks so much for the solution and explanation. This is exactly what I was looking for.


Out of curiosity, assuming I wasn't already aware that onClick expected a function, how would I know based on its signature that it's expecting a function? I just don't understand how I would solve this problem organically just based on the types.

I realize this might be a super fundamental question and I will probably become familiar with this with time learning typescript

Comment: `onClick` is an event, and you need to provide an event handler which, as with the most of the events, is most commonly a function that takes the event as parameter. Even in vanilla HTML. This function is where you decide what to do with it the event object. Submit a form, show a modal, or change theme... I personally rely on VSCode auto-suggest to see signatures but you can also refer the docs: [React Cheatsheet](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forms_and_events), [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#function-signature-2)